# Firefox div object height

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="radioplayer">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="467" height="26">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.museter.com/ffmp3-config.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="url=http://stream.../;&lang=nl&codec=mp3&volume=65&introurl=&autoplay=false&traking=true&jsevents=false&buffering=5&skin=http://www.museter.com/skins/eastanbul/ffmp3-eastanbul.xml&title=Zottebeatjes&welcome=Welkom" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <embed src="http://www.museter.com/ffmp3-config.swf" flashvars="url=http://stream.../;&lang=nl&codec=mp3&volume=65&introurl=&autoplay=false&traking=true&jsevents=false&buffering=5&skin=http://www.museter.com/skins/eastanbul/ffmp3-eastanbul.xml&title=Zottebeatjes&welcome=Welkom" width="467" scale="noscale" height="26" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    </object>
</div>
<div id="streaminfobar">
    *some info*
</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS stylesheet:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    display: table;
}
* {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
#radioplayer {
    width: 100%;
    height:26px;
    background-color: #222222;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-row;
}
#streaminfobar {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:0;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    display: table-row;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/CXBeE/

The problem is that the radioplayer div has to have height 26 px, as specified in the css block. In Google Chrome it is indeed 26 px, but in Firefox and in Internet Explorer it's lot's more than 26 px.

In firefox it's like this:

[image: In firefox]

But it should be like this (in chrome):

[image: In Google Chrome]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why did you put this in the css?
* {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}

Comment: @RupamDatta Because else the div's won't fill the whole page, there will be white borders without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `*{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}` 
 to `body, html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}`. 
You only want those two to be 100% high, not every element in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is missing a closing div. Or is that just a bug in this simplified example?

Comment: Sorry, it's indeed a bug in the example